# Teradata extraction by pyspark2 is taking long time

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I am trying to extract maximum date from teradata table thru pyspark2. While the simple query is running for few seconds in Teradata, in spark after 1 hour of execution it is not giving me any answer.

I am executing pyspark2 in CLI, and I already kept  tdgssconfig.jar,terajdbc4.jar in the same location

```
pyspark2 --conf spark.ui.port=45321 --jars tdgssconfig.jar,terajdbc4.jar

TD_QUERY = "(select max({a}) as max_date from {b}) as temp".format(a=Partition_Info,b=SOURCE_TABLE_VIEW)
df_td_date = spark.read\
  .format("jdbc")\
  .option("url",connection_url)\
  .option("driver",connection_driver)\
  .option("dbtable",TD_QUERY)\
  .option("user",user_name)\
  .option("password",pwd)\
  .load()
max_date_temp = df_td_max_date.collect()
```

Please let me know, if I need to improve any part of this code?